# Pandas dataframe if else condition based on previous rows

Tags: python-3.x

I have a pandas dataframe as below:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'X':[1,1,1, 0, 0]})
df

    X
0   1
1   1
2   1
3   0
4   0
```

Now I want to create another variable 'Y' and Values for Y should be based on the below condition:

```
If X = 1 , Y=1
If X = 0 and previous X = 1, Y = 2
If X = 0 and previous x = 0, Y = 0
```

So, my final output should look like below:

```
    X    Y
0   1    1    
1   1    1
2   1    1
3   0    2
4   0    0
```

This can be achieved by iterating over rows and setting up a current and previous row and using iloc but I want a more efficient way of doing this faster

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try using `np.where` and `shift`:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df = pd.DataFrame({'X':[1,1,1, 0, 0]})
df['Y'] = np.where(df['X'] == 1,1,np.where(df['X'].shift(periods=1) == 1,2,0))
print(df)
```

Output:

```
   X  Y
0  1  1
1  1  1
2  1  1
3  0  2
4  0  0
```

Answer (score 0):

Celius provided an answer with nested calls to `np.where`. This can become unfeasible if the number of conditions grow. You can use `np.select` instead to achieve the same result:

```py
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd


df = pd.DataFrame({
    'X': [1, 1, 1, 0, 0]
})
conditions = [
    df["X"] == 1,
    (df["X"] == 0) & (df["X"].shift() == 1),
    (df["X"] == 0) & (df["X"].shift() == 0)
]
values = [1, 2, 0]
df['Y'] = np.select(conditions, values, default=np.nan)
```